# Asymptotic equivalence and Kolmogorov-Smirnov Distance

Tags: distance, asymptotics

Suppose we have two sequences of random variables $\{X_k\}$ and $\{Y_k\}$, both converging to the same distribution, say $N(0,V)$, for some covariance matrix $V$. Does this imply that
$$\sup_{u}\left|F_{X_k}(u) - F_{Y_k}(u)\right| \to 0$$ in probability as $k \to \infty$? Here $F_{X_k}$ denotes the c.d.f. of $X_k$. Intuitively, it seems obvious that this holds, but are there any reasons why this might not be true? A related question - are there any necessary conditions for this claim to hold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends in what sense $X_k$ and $Y_k$ converges to $N(0,V)$. Let us denote by $KS$ the Kolmogorov-Smirnov distance, if we have
$$KS(X_k,Z)\xrightarrow[k \to \infty]{}0 $$
$$KS(Y_k,Z)\xrightarrow[k \to \infty]{}0 $$
where $Z \sim N(0,V)$, then by triangular inequality
$$KS(X_k,Y_k)\le KS(X_k,Z)+KS(Z,Y_k)\xrightarrow[k \to \infty]{}0 .$$
Hence the result you enunciated is true because the convergence in KS implies the convergence in law if the targeted law is continuous (see for example [Convergence in law implies convergence in total variation for polynomials in independent Gaussian,Gamma or Beta random variables](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00821911/document)).

On the other hand, if the convergence is just "in law" and towards a law that is not continuous  i.e. it is just a convergence in the weak topology then we don't know. Because we have that if $X_k$ converges to $Z$ for KS, then it converges weakly to $Z$ but the converse is not true in general : KS does not metrize the weak topology.